# Emotion: Using both a class and the "css" method in "className" prop

Tags: reactjs, emotion

How can both a class plus additional CSS be applied when Emotion is used with the `className` prop in React?

For example, how can one add a class `myClass` to the following?

```
import {css} from 'emotion'

<div className={css`color: red`}>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never used Emotion but it looks like you can simply add your class and another template string around the `css` function.

```
<div className={`myClass ${css`color: red`}`}>
```

I tested this with one of their inline editors on a page in their Introduction then checked the markup. Seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

emotion v11 answer

```
import { css, ClassNames } from '@emotion/react'

const orange = css`color:orange;`
const bold = css`font-weight:bold;`

render(
  <>
    Using ClassNames
    <br/>
    <ClassNames>
      {({ css, cx, theme }) => (
          <>
            <div className={`case1 ${css`color:red;`}`}>Case1</div>
            <div className={cx('case2', css`color:green;`)}>Case2</div>
            <div className={cx('case3', css`${orange}`)}>Case3</div>
            <div className="Case4" css={orange}>Case4</div>
            <div className="Case6" css={[orange, bold]}>Case5</div>
            <div className={cx('case6', orange)}>Case6 (not working)</div>
          </>
      )}
    </ClassNames>
    <br/>
    without ClassNames
    <br/>
     <>
            <div className={`raw1 ${css`color:red;`}`}>Raw1 (now working)</div>
            <div className="raw2" css={orange}>Case4</div>
            <div className="raw3" css={[orange, bold,'abc']}>Case5 (no abc)</div>
          </>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for handy reference. I didn’t notice at first that some of your examples are marked with “not working”.

Answer (score 0):

You can use composes with regular classes or classes from a css module

```
<div className={css`
  composes: ${'some-class'};
  color: red;` >
```

May be this can help you if you are still stuck [click here](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/86b4a61d0db7446f9aab60ecd70d76b2453c9f26/docs/composes.md)

Comment: Unfortunately, the class I want to add is external—it's not defined outside of my React/Emotion environment.

Comment: . . . so I still need to include the actual class name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `cx` compose method provided in their docs for this usecase.

```
import { css, cx } from '@emotion/css'

export const Button = () => {
  return (
    <div
      className={cx('otherClassName', css`background-color: hotpink;`)}>
      Hover to change color
    </div>
)}
```

[link to docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition)